# Matrices with Operator Norm 1

Tags: linear-algebra

I believe the following claim is true, and I have a proof, but I'm still not sure. It seems like something I would have encountered by now if it were true.

Suppose an matrix $A=(a_{ij})\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ has $\|A\|=1$ where $\|\cdot\|$ here denotes the operator norm, i.e. $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} |Ax|$ (where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean norm). Then, $|a_{ij}|\leq 1$ for each $i,j\in \{1,...,n\}$.

Proof: Suppose there exist $i,j\in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $|a_{i,j}|>1$. Then, 
$$\left|\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} & ... & a_{1,n}\\ ... & a_{i,j} & ...\\ a_{n,1} &... & a_{n,n}\end{bmatrix} \cdot e_j\right|=\left|\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,j} \\...\\a_{i,j}\\...\\a_{n,j}\end{bmatrix}\right|=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |a_{k,j}|^2\right)^{1/2}>1$$

Since $|e_j|=1$, $\|A\|>1$, $\rightarrow \leftarrow$.

Is this right, if so is there another theorem or idea that gets at it more intuitively? If not, counterexample please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct and I think it captures exactly the right intuition. Having $\|A\| \leq 1$ means exactly that $| A e| \leq 1$ for every unit vector $e$. In particular, the image of each standard basis unit vector has Euclidean norm at most $1$. That is, the columns of $A$ must each have Euclidean norm at most $1$, which entails that each entry of $A$ have magnitude at most $1$.

You might consider rephrasing to avoid using proof by contradiction. For example, you could just write

$$ |a_{ij}| \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{k,j}|^2 \right)^{1/2} = | A e_j | \leq \|A\| \cdot |e_j| \ = 1.$$