# Matrices with Operator Norm $\leq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a follow-up conjecture to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766731/matrices-with-operator-norm-1) I posed yesterday. 
The proof in that question should extend to show that if a matrix $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ has operator norm $\|A\|\leq 1$, then $|a_{ij}|\leq 1$ for each $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$. Is the converse true? That is, if $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ has $|a_{i,j}|\leq 1$ for each $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$, does $A$ have operator norm $\|A\|\leq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider $A=(a_{ij})\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $a_{ij}=1$ for all $i$ and $j$ and the operator $p$-norm with $p=1$ or $p=\infty$. In both cases, $\|A\|_p=n$.

For $p=2$, it is generally not true neither. Consider
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \quad \|A\|_2=2.
$$

Generally, the sharpest bound you can get for the 2-norm is $n$, which follows simply from
the fact that the 2-norm is bounded from above by the Frobenius norm which is bounded by $n$ if all entries of the matrix have absolute values bounded by 1:
$$
\|A\|_2\leq\|A\|_F=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^2}\leq n.
$$
The bound is attained, e.g., by the matrix of all ones.